# How to render Flask output to a string instead of browser

Tags: python, flask

I have a template (.html file) that I want to render to a string instead of sending the rendered result to a browser.

I expected something like this to work, where the rendered html code is assigned to output as a string:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    output = render_template("template.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
    print(output)
```

**Templates/template.html**

```
<h1>some random text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manually push the required context might have solved the problem for me:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    template = render_template("template.html")
```

returning the string

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to escape the HTML tag and display the content in templete.html as a string on a browser you can use escape as shown below:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from markupsafe import escape, Markup
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    output = render_template("template.html")
    return escape(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```